# SetInterval function calls

Tags: javascript, function, setinterval

I am getting into sort of confusion here. Please go through the below code,

```
<script>

setInterval(function1,3000);

setInterval(function2(),3000);

function function1() {
    console.log("Function1 called....");
}

function function2() {
    console.log("Function2 called....");
}

</script>
```

As you can see I have two `setInterval` functions one calls function like `function1` and another `function2()`. The output of first is perfect that gets called every 3sec and first call after 3sec. But second one gets called without the delay i.e `function2`.

I guess that `()` might be doing things there but I'm not sure about what I'm missing there. I just want to know what is happening there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second `setInterval` you are executing it right away and plugging the value returned by that function into `setInterval`.

For example,

```
setInterval(a(), 5000);
function a(){
    return function(){
        console.log("Executed!");
    };
};
```

`a()` executed and returning the `function` into `setInterval`. You should see the console is writing `Executed` every 5 seconds.

This is just like math:

```
f(x) = x + 1
g(x) = 2

f(g(2)) = g(x) + 2 = 4
You replace g(2) with whatever it returns
(you replace a() with the function in this case)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/39wNn/

Answer (score 3):

`setInterval(function1,3000);` instructs the JS engine to execute the function `function1` every 3 seconds.

`setInterval(function2(),3000);` instructs the JS engine to run `function2` **once**, then run the return value every 3 seconds. This return value is empty.

For a bit of fun try

```
function function2() {
    console.log("Function2 called....");
    return "function3();"
}

function function3() {
    console.log("Function3 called....");
}

setInterval(function2(),3000);
```

**Edit**

In reponse to @harsha's comment: What do I mean by "run the return value"

`setInterval(function2(),3000);` will trigger the following workflow:

- Initiate executing `function2()` (execute it, because it the brackets are given).
- `function2` runs to completion, then returns.
- - In your OQ, there is no return value from the function so it is `null`
- - The return value of my function2 is the string "function3();"
- This return value is now inserted into the `setInterval()` call
- - The OQ version results in `setInterval(null, 3000);`, which does nothing every 3 seconds
- - My version results in `setInterval("function3();", 3000)`, which calls `eval("function3();");` every 3 seconds, which in turn runs `function3` every 3 seconds.

Comment: what exactly is 'run the return value'?I would love to understand.

Comment: @harsha - Basically `eval([returned value]);`

Comment: +1 got to know more. and thanks to you both Eugen and harsha.

Comment: @EugenRieck : Take a bow.Wonderfully explained.

Answer (score 1):

The () makes the function get executed immediately in the second case. In the first case, just the pointer to function which gets executed later as the call back function.